# Wordpress Custom Post Type Sorting Filter - Combine queries to sort by multiple values

Tags: wordpress, filtering, custom-post-type

I have a query that sorts my custom post types by a taxonomy (length) that I set-up. I'd like to be able to control some of the placement of the post types so I was thinking of using WP's Menu Order in addition. Is there a way to combine my sort by length query and the Menu Order query so that Menu Order results appear first by length then the rest of the results continue by length?

Here is the filter by length query:

```
/* Custom Filter Begin */ 
do_action( 'wpc_filtered_query_end', $query );
  function wpb_custom_query( $query ) {
     if ( $query->is_category() )  
        {$query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );  }
elseif( $query->is_main_query() && ! is_admin() && $query->is_archive() ) {
    
    $query->set( 'meta_key', 'length' );
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
    $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
}
} add_action( 'wpc_filtered_query_end', 'wpb_custom_query' );
/* Custom Filter End */
```

Something like this?:

```
$query->set( 'orderby', 'menu_order' );
$query->set( 'order' , 'DESC' );
```